# Date Math in Postgres Column + 2/24

Tags: postgresql

How can I convert this from Oracle to Postgres? I've tried using Interval, but Interval doesn't seem to like dividing

```
COALESCE(column1GMT, Column2GMT) + 2/24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `interval`:

```
COALESCE(column1GMT, Column2GMT) + interval '1 day' * (2.0 / 24)
```

Comment: `interval '1 day' * (2.0 / 24)` can be simplified to `interval '2 hour'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not sure but probably 2 will be a parameter.

Comment: Then it can be done using `make_interval(hours => ?)` or `interval '1 hour' * ?`

Comment: Sure, but this is code provides the equivalent code from the OP's Oracle code.